# How to properly report confidence from distance/threshold (face detection)

Tags: confidence-interval, roc, accuracy, precision-recall

In the context of face matching I have the following histogram:

[image]

blue bins count the comparison distances for "self matches" (comparing two images of the same person). Orange bins count the distances for cross matches (different persons).

The distance is the value returned by the neural networks as the result of a comparison between two faces, how much two "faces vectors" differ. Given two pictures the distance is small if the faces are similar.

I'd like to map the raw distance that I get from the neural network to something that "looks like a percentage" or even better a proper confidence value.

For example with distance of 0.5 I would expect a very very high confidence practically 100%. Most of the self matches falls here and none of the cross ever return this value.

At a distance of 1.0 only 2% of the self matches reports this value or a greater one but again none of the cross matches reaches this value. I think the confidence is lower than before but still very high, like 99.x%.

The danger zone is close to 1.4/1.5 so here the number should be close to 50% and get quickly smaller from there. How can I translate this intuition that is clearly visible from the chart into a formally correct number?

I suspect something like ROC should be used, but I'm looking for something with this shape:

[image]

EDIT: the problem with metrics like specificity is this:

```
Confusion Matrix at 0.5 :  
 10000     0  
 5823  4177  
Accuracy :  0.70885  
Sensitivity :  1.0  
Specificity :  0.4177  

Confusion Matrix at 1.4:  
 9999    1  
 50 9950  
Accuracy :  0.99745  
Sensitivity :  0.9999  
Specificity :  0.995
```

This numbers are very different from what I'm looking for (see the red curve above).

What I'm looking for is something like: if the distance is close to 1.4 there is an xx% of probability that these two are the same persons. In practice if I compare a large number of random pairs, self and cross matches, I should see that the value 1.4 is found for self and cross matches an equal number of times.

**In other words: given the distance X, and this distribution, how likely it is that these two are from the same person?**

Comment: Isn't that just the proportion of true negatives? Close enough to specificity... but I'm not sure what distance you're talking about.

Comment: @Calimo The distance is the value returned by the neural networks as the result of a comparison between two faces. How much two faces vectors differ. It is the value I use as a threshold match/no match. I have updated the question with more details.